# ExpandableListView, how do I change the text size of group headers?

Tags: java, android

I am able to change the text size of a group item (the header of each group in the ExpandableListView), but when I do, the little arrow next to the header title that indicates if the group is expanded gets clipped by the newly enlarged text. Is there something else I need to do when I change the size of the header text so the layout doesn't look like that?

[image: ExpandableListView]

Also, is there a way to put the text to the right of the arrow indicator instead of to the left?

Comment: By arrow do you mean check mark? Also, post your xml!

Comment: Nevermind, I forgot to set the padding of the text. It works now.